# Responsive text box jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I have label and text box in jQuery mobile and when the screen size changes the whole structure changes too.

When i have screen size width less then 448px it goes to label and text box under the label but when it is above 447px it is one next to the other.

I am adding two photos in order to be clear.

This is the code:

Html:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                 <label for="sales1">Sales:</label>
                 <input type="text" id="sales" value="">
            </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.ui-field-contain .ui-input-text {
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

[image: One next to the other]

[image: One under the other]

Is there any way by css to override it and to be always one next to the other in any screen size?

Comment: I don't see ```.ui-input-text``` in the HTML.. Is it something jQuery mobile is adding?

Comment: you do not need to pay attention to it. this is only changes the size of the text box. without it it will be 100% size but still what i mentioned will happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm paying attention to it.. I'm wired like that - trying to spot an issue and I see there is a CSS class that is not referenced in HTML... Maybe you can provide http://plnkr.co/ link?

Comment: Sorry for that, just pasted my code. This css is not in the html it is something from jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to style label as an block on small screens

```
@media (max-width: 448px) {
  .ui-field-contain label {
    display: block;
  }
}
```